# A more clean approach to sorting a string into another string

Tags: c#, string, linq, string-formatting

I have a string that might look something like this: "3, 7, 12-14, 1, 5-6"

What i need to do is to change that into a string looking like this: "1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14"

I have made the following code work, but i would very much appreciated help how to do this a cleaner way with less lines of code:

```
private string sortLanes(string lanesString)
    {
        List<string> sortedLanes = new List<string>();

        if (lanesString.Contains(',') || lanesString.Contains('-'))
        {
            List<string> laneParts = lanesString.Split(',').ToList();

            foreach (string lanePart in laneParts)
            {
                if (lanePart.Contains('-'))
                {
                    int splitIndex = lanePart.IndexOf('-');
                    int lanePartLength = lanePart.Length;

                    int firstLane = Convert.ToInt32(lanePart.Substring(0, splitIndex));
                    int lastLane = Convert.ToInt32(lanePart.Substring(splitIndex + 1, lanePartLength - splitIndex - 1));
                    while (firstLane != lastLane)
                    {
                        sortedLanes.Add(firstLane.ToString().Trim());
                        firstLane++;
                    }
                    sortedLanes.Add(lastLane.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    sortedLanes.Add(lanePart.Trim());
                }
            }
            sortedLanes.Sort();
            sortedLanes = sortedLanes.OrderBy(x => x.Length).ToList();

            lanesString = "";
            foreach (string lane in sortedLanes)
            {
                if (lanesString.Length == 0)
                {
                    lanesString = lane;
                }
                else
                {
                    lanesString = lanesString + ", " + lane;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return lanesString;
        }
        return lanesString;
    }
```

Comment: -1 for "better" when you don't provide the metric by which you define "better". What is it? Lines of Code? Speed? Memory usage? Least number of variables? Phase of the moon? Something else?

Comment: @Oded Im sorry, i will update the question. My thoughts on making it "better" was Cleaner code and also less lines.

Comment: Define "Cleaner code"...

Comment: @Oded Well i guess it would proberly just mean less lines of code

Comment: well as a start the `else { return lanesString; }` is completely unnecessary, as it's then written on the next line.

Comment: This is one for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first split by the `,` then convert each value into either a single integer or the desired range.  Take the results and reorder them and then concatenate back into a string.  Something like this.

```
    string test = "3, 7, 12-14, 1, 5-6";
    var items = test.Split(',');
    var ints = items.SelectMany(item => Expand(item));
    string result = string.Join(", ", ints.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray());


    private static IEnumerable<int> Expand(string str)
    {
        if (str.Contains('-'))
        {
            var range = str.Split('-');
            int begin = int.Parse(range[0]);
            int end = int.Parse(range[1]);
            for (int i = begin; i <= end; i++)
                yield return i;
        }
        else
            yield return int.Parse(str);
    }
```

Of course you might want to add some error checking, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Nice solution, clean and understandable

Comment: @juharr Yes this was a very nice solution, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This will produce the wanted result (partially based on the [incorrect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13823591/1583) from @Tigran):

```
var parts = "3, 7, 12-14, 1, 5-6".Split(new string[] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

var finalResult = new List<int>();
foreach(var item in parts)
{
    if(item.Contains("-"))
    {
        var rangeParts = item.Split('-');
        var first = int.Parse(rangeParts[0]);
        var second = int.Parse(rangeParts[1]);

        var result = Enumerable.Range(first, second - first + 1); 

        finalResult.AddRange(result);
    }
    else
    {
       finalResult.Add(int.Parse(item));
    }
}
var sorted = finalResult.OrderBy(i => i);
var resultString = string.Join(", ", sorted);
```

Comment: why do not just immediately split on "-" too?

Comment: @Tigran - Then how would you tell that `3,7` should just produce `3` and `7` and not `3,4,5,6,7`? You need to treat ranges differently from single numbers.

Comment: @Odded: ok, correct. But another thing yet,  expected result is "**1**, 3, 5, 6, 7", in your case 1  doesn't exist.

Comment: This doesn't compile (you use `var result` twice) but is the first right answer I have seen including all those that have been deleted!

Comment: @Oded: I downvoted you, cause the result is **not** what OP would expect (at least according to the question)

Comment: @Tigran - I suggest you run the code and inspect what the OP posted as the wanted result against the contents of `resultString`.

Comment: @Oded: ok :) my wrong pardon me. I just looked on the code, after running it I saw it and saw why. +1 definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Regex would work nicely here...

```
static void Main()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14", Transform("3, 7, 12-14, 1, 5-6"));
}

private static string Transform(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(Match m in new Regex(@"(?<start>\d+)(?:-(?<end>\d+))?(?:,|$)\s*").Matches(input)
        .OfType<Match>().OrderBy(m => int.Parse(m.Groups["start"].Value)))
    {
        int start = int.Parse(m.Groups["start"].Value);
        int end = !m.Groups["end"].Success ? start : int.Parse(m.Groups["end"].Value);
        foreach (int val in Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1))
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}, ", val);
    }

    if (sb.Length > 0)
        sb.Length = sb.Length - 2;//remove trailing comma+space;
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**Update**

If I wanted to make it confusing I'd just use a single line of code:

```
return String.Join(", ",new Regex(@"(?<start>\d+)(?:-(?<end>\d+))?(?:,|$)\s*").Matches(input)
    .OfType<Match>().OrderBy(m => int.Parse(m.Groups["start"].Value)).SelectMany(m => 
        Enumerable.Range(int.Parse(m.Groups["start"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["end"].Success
        ? m.Groups["end"].Value : m.Groups["start"].Value) - int.Parse(m.Groups["start"].Value) + 1))
    .Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

LoL :)

Comment: Yes, if you want to confuse 90% of all programmers as to what your code does.

Comment: You think only 10% of all programmers can read a regex?  That's harsh.

Comment: No, just regex with a lot of back references.

Comment: There, now it's confusing ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you like Linq:

```
string input = "3, 7, 12-14, 1, 5-6";
List<int> all = input.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(r => new
    {
        Range = r,
        Parts = r.Split(new[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Select(p => int.Parse(p))
    })
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(x.Parts.First(), 1 + x.Parts.Last() - x.Parts.First()))
    .ToList();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/BYbEUZ)